# Find the sum explicitly in the interval of convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find the sum explicitly in the interval of convergence of the series.

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{n}{n+1}\left(2x-1\right)^n$

Here is the work that I did:

$let\:t\:=\:2x-1$

$\frac{n}{n+1}\:=\:1\:-\:\frac{1}{n+1}$

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{n}{n+1}t^n\:=\:\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:t^n\:-\:\sum \:_{n=1}^{\infty \:}\:\frac{1}{n+1}t^n\:=\:\frac{1}{1-t}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n+1}t^n$

$f\left(t\right)\:=\:\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n+1}t^n$

$tf\left(t\right)\:=\:\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n+1}t^{n+1}$

And here is where my work differs from the solution of the problem.

While I do: $\frac{d}{dx}\left(tf\left(t\right)\right)\:=\:\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:t^n\:=\:\frac{1}{1-t}$

The solution says: $\frac{d}{dx}\left(tf\left(t\right)\right)\:=\:\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:t^n\:=\:\frac{t}{1-t}$

Following by an integration step and dividing by t. Which one is the correct approach and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:t^n = t+t^2+\cdots \implies \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:t^n= t (1+t+t^2+\cdots)=t + t\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:t^n \implies \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:t^n = \frac{t}{1-t}$. It seems you misread the sum as $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\cdots$